# Set Order Status to Complete After Payment - from another site

Tags: php, order

We need to do a external call for updating the order status. Is there a webhook so we can do a order status update from another site?

Here is the code when updating internally (on the same site):

```
add_filter (‘woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status’, ‘my_change_status_function’);

function my_change_status_function ($order_id) { 
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    //Do whatever additional logic you like before….
    return ‘completed’;
}

add_action( ‘woocommerce_order_status_completed’, ‘my_post_order_status_change_function’ );
```

But we need to do this from another site - howto? :-)

Comment: You need to have some sort of access to the external site.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/using-woocommerce-rest-api-orders-endpoint/